# Get Windows Folder Security Properties using Python or Command Line

Tags: windows, security, winapi

In Windows, if I <kbd>ALT</kbd>-Click on a folder and then select `Properties`->`Security`, I can see a list of groups and user names. How do I do this programmatically from Python? If needbe, I can run a command line (powershell) function, but I cannot use any special packages that need to be installed.